# Hana SQL help needed

Tags: sql, hana

I have a requirement like below. I have table like the below one :

```
ID  SID  VID  VTXT
1    10  v_5   Five
1    10  v_5   asd
2    11  v_7   Seven
2    11  v_7   seven
3    12  v_9   NINE
3    12  v_9   Nine
3    12  v_9   nine
```

I need the output as :

```
ID  SID  VID  VTXT
1    10  v_5   Five
2    10  v_5   asd
1    11  v_7   Seven
2    11  v_7   seven
1    12  v_9   NINE
2    12  v_9   Nine
3    12  v_9   nine
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: There is almost no detail here. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know the syntax of tags you made if this is for sql-server it'd be

```
update table 
set ID=(select rn=row_number() over(partition by ID order by ID) from table)
```

Comment: You could just have a select statement instead of updating the table. OP doesn't explicitly say he wants to update his source table.

Comment: Hi,
I need to Update the table. But i am getting syntax error in rn=row_number. Can you plz explain this.

Comment: can you make a sql-fiddle demo for this ? so that i can look into ! or look into documentation of row_number () in your _rdbms_

Comment: i m getting the select query returns more than one value exception.

Comment: I executed select query it gives me exact result but i am not able to update the values. i m getting the above exception.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to order the results like that?

```
Order by SID, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function with Partition By clause

Here is the sample

```
SELECT row_number() AS ID, 
    SID, 
    VID, 
    VTXT
FROM VTable;
```

Partition By enables renumbering of rows in the group defined by each combination of PARTITION BY clause column values.

You can refer to [SQL Row_Number](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) samples at referred document hoping to be useful